# Social login redirect

Tags: apex, single-sign-on, oauth

This is my first contact with salesforce, so please don't get mad at my silly questions :)
I am struggling to configure a login with facebook using salesforce. I went trough the [example](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_provider_facebook.htm&language=en#facebook_update) and I got it working until the point where it logins with facebook, and it return an xml response.

My question is: how can I configure salesforce to not take me to an xml page after login, but redirect back to my site with a user id in the url?

From what I have found, I am supposed to [modify](http://abhisheksubbu.com/2014/10/customizing-registrationhandler-apex-codesalesforce-openid-connect-auth-providers/) the registration handler and insert the logic there, but I can't figure out how to specify the redirect url, since I am returning an user object.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the test SSO URL working, returning the XML structure, you should be able to use the 'Single Sign-On Initialization URL' to do SSO. Your registration handler maps the incoming data from Facebook (essentially what you're seeing in the XML) to a User object. If all is working well, you'll be logged in to Salesforce as that user.

Taking things further, you can then put that URL on a page for users to initiate SSO, or configure a login page via My Domain, or Community Settings, that will show a button for Facebook login.